# mysql database priority order

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I know the mysql database is not in any particular oder, but I need it to behave in an ordered way. I have a database, example below, which currently seems to be in the order of column 1 (jobID, auto increment, primary key). What I need to do is to to change the order by, for example, moving the 3rd row up one position, so essentially changing the position of the 3rd and 2nd row, but I am unsure of how to do this. The reason is I am accessing this database via a python app which is grabbing jobs from a list, and I need to change the priority order sometimes. What would be the best way to do this please?

```
+-------+---------+----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| jobID | location| mode     | process | status | submitTime          |
+-------+---------+----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
|     1 | /let111/| Verify   | 1       | Failed | 2014-06-25 12:24:38 |
|     2 | /let114/| Verify   | 1       | Passed | 2014-06-25 12:37:31 |
|     3 | /let112/| Verify   | 1       | Failed | 2014-06-25 14:48:55 |
|     4 | /let117/| Verify   | 2       | Passed | 2014-06-25 14:49:01 |
|     5 | /let113/| Verify   | 2       | Passed | 2014-06-25 14:49:13 |
+-------+---------+----------+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Are you just trying to order by `status`?

Comment: No, this is my question, do I need to create another column, and somehow number it on entry, then change that number, then re-order? I don't know.

Comment: Add new column `my_order` if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order by status first and then time, use an `order by` clause:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by status, submitTime;
```

In general, tables in relational databases in general and MySQL in particular have no particular order because a table models an *unordered* set of tuples.  You can get results back in a particular order by using `order by`.

Note that the above is just one possibility that accomplishes what you are asking for.  What you really want might involve other columns.